# can we use paramiko to execute command over multiple shell

Tags: python, paramiko

```
hosts=['10.101.x.x'] username='root' password=''


from datetime import datetime date = datetime.now() dates
=date.strftime('%d%b%Y') print dates CheckStr = "Log-" + dates print CheckStr

cmd1='cd /usr/local/element/log/global/log/;ls -ltr' cmd2='/usr/local/element/rel/RAN_RCS_1.0.0.31/bin/linux-x86_pcm64/execCmdCli' cmd3='element add filter rule SPNLOGS enable class SPNAPP severity Informational,Major,Debug,Critical,Minor target log'

def work_comp():

    for host in hosts:
        print host

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        global ssh
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password, timeout=5.0 )
        exe_comm(cmd1)
        exe_comm(cmd2)
        ssh.close()
        # cmd='cd /usr/local/element/log/global/log/;ls -ltr'
        # cmd2='pwd'
        # #cmd2='/usr/local/element/rel/RAN_RCS_1.0.0.31/bin/linux-x86_pcm64/execCmdCli'
        # cmd3='element add filter rule SPNLOGS enable class SPNAPP severity Informational,Major,Debug,Critical,Minor target log'
        # #cmd5="date |awk '{print $2,$3,$6}'"


def exe_comm(cmd):

        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        for line in stdout:
            print (line)
        print "Done"

work_comp()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [parallel SSH client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parallel-ssh) (uses paramiko) that can do this which is also asynchronous.

```
from pssh import ParallelSSHClient
client = ParallelSSHClient(['10.101.x.x'], user='root', password='')

cmd1='cd /usr/local/element/log/global/log/;ls -ltr'
cmd2='/usr/local/element/rel/RAN_RCS_1.0.0.31/bin/linux-x86_pcm64/execCmdCli'
cmd3='element add filter rule SPNLOGS enable class SPNAPP severity Informational,Major,Debug,Critical,Minor target log'

for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
    output = client.run_command(cmd)
    for host, host_out in output.items():
        for line in host_out.stdout:
            print("[%s] - %s" % (host, line,))
    print("done")
```